# Telegram bot - problem with function sync blocking

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot written in python that lets users create EC2 instances in AWS. The code is the following:

```
# We create the new EC2 instance for the new user
instance_id, ec2 = generateInstanceForUser(user_id)

i = ec2.Instance(id=instance_id) # instance id
i.start()
i.wait_until_running()
i.load()
time.sleep(45)

# Create account in DB
createAccountDB(user_id, username, user.mail, instance_id)

# Now that the instance and the account have been created, now settings have to be updated too
updateSettings(user_id, dictChange)
```

The problem is that function `generateInstanceForUser(user_id)` is blocking the workflow, as well as the following 5 lines (obvious, with `time.sleep()` function). The last function `updateSettings()` connects via SSH to the just created machine and do some operations. Without considering delays, this workflow works well.

HOWEVER, since I am using a Telegram bot, during this portion of the code the bot freezes during 2 minutes. As a result, if there are other users sending commands, the bot does not respond, and that is not desirable, obviously.

NOTE: functions used are held in the boto3 library.

## QUESTION

Do you know some alternative to avoid workflow blocking during the execution of the given code in order to avoid bad UX with Telegram bot? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer. I just encapsuled the blocking portion of the code inside another function, and used threading in order to create a parallel thread. This way, the main thread would not block and the bot would still keep working normally:

```
threads = []
t = threading.Thread(target=workerFunc, args=(apiKey, apiSecret, user_id, startStepValue, username, user, bot, update, leverageValue))
threads.append(t)
t.start()
```